# Изменение изображения в реальном времени

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Есть список услуг, в каждой услуге своя картинка, когда я нажимаю кнопку "Редактировать" в правой панели подгружаются все данные о выбранной услуге, включая изображение, если я меняю это изображение через кнопку "Изменить изображение" и нажимаю "Сохранить", то путь до картинки в БД сохраняется, но отображается эта измененная картинка в списке услуг только после перезапуска приложения, а нужно, чтобы сразу как только я его поменял оно в списке услуг отобразилось

Класс MainViewModel

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

public class ApplicationViewModel : VM
{
    SvetlanaDmitrievnaEntities dataEntities;
    public ObservableCollection<Service_import> Services { get; private set; }

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        dataEntities = new SvetlanaDmitrievnaEntities();
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(_=> Save());
        ChangeImageCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(_ => ChangeImage());
        EditCommand = new RelayCommand<Service_import>(Edit);
    }

    // Команда редактирования объекта
    private void Edit(Service_import service)
    {
        SelectedService = service;
    }

    private void ChangeImage()
    {
        string sourceImg;
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Выберите изображение";
        op.Filter = "Все форматы|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Png|*.png";

        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            sourceImg = op.FileName;
            SelectedService.Главное_изображение = sourceImg;
        }
    }

    // Команда сохранения изменений
    public ICommand EditCommand { get; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }
    public ICommand ChangeImageCommand { get; }

    private void Save()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(SelectedService.Главное_изображение.ToString());
        var item = dataEntities.Service_import.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Наименование_услуги == SelectedService.Наименование_услуги);
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Наименование_услуги = SelectedService.Наименование_услуги;
            item.Длительность = SelectedService.Длительность;
            item.Стоимость = SelectedService.Стоимость;
            item.Главное_изображение = SelectedService.Главное_изображение;
            item.Действующая_скидка = SelectedService.Действующая_скидка;
            dataEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private Service_import selectedService;
    public Service_import SelectedService
    {
        get { return selectedService; }
        set
        {
            selectedService = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedService");
        }
    }
}
```

View: ( Панели редактирования услуги, правой )

```
<StackPanel x:Name="editServicePanel" Height="481" Margin="444,123,26.6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label x:Name="labelPanelId" Content="Номер услуги" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxPaneId" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService.id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="5,0,0.2,0" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelPanel1" Content="Наименование услуги" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxPanel1" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService.Наименование_услуги, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="5,0,0.2,0"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelPanel2" Content="Стоимость" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0.2,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxPanel2" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="5,0,0.2,0" Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService.Стоимость, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelPanel3" Content="Длительность" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxPanel3" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService.Длительность, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="5,0,0.2,0"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelPanel4" Content="Скидка" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textboxPanel4" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService.Действующая_скидка, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Padding="0,3,0,0" Margin="5,0,0.2,0"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelPanel5" Content="Основное изображение" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="5,8,5,5"/>
        <DockPanel Height="100" LastChildFill="False">
            <Image x:Name="editImage" Source="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="182"/>
            <Button x:Name="editImageBtn" Content="Изменить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="5,35,0,35" Width="127" Background="#E5FF6856" Foreground="White" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Cursor="Hand" Click="editImageBtn_Click" Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Сохранить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="5,30,0,0" Width="177" Background="#E5FF6856" Foreground="White" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Cursor="Hand" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

P.s данные с текстбоксов изменяются в реальном времени, а вот изображение почему-то нет

Comment: `Binding DataContext.SelectedService.Главное_изображение`, и уберите из этого биндинга `UpdateSourceTrigger`, оно там не надо. `UpdateSourceTrigger` нужен там, где вы хотите немедленно обновить данные вьюмодели при изменении данных в интерфейсе, а не наоборот.

Comment: @aepot я и так тоже делал, и сейчас ещё раз попробовал, всё равно не помогает, причём в текстбоксах привязка та же самая и всё работает, а с изображением ничего

Comment: @aepot Так а я же картинку тоже в интерфейсе меняю, нажимаю на кнопку "Изменить", выбираю с компа картинку и она должна автоматически подставиться и в левую панель с услугой и в правую панель, где само редактирование изображения

Comment: У вашей кнопки рядом с картинкой указаны обработчик события `Click` и команда `Command`. Выберите что-то одно. И обновите разметку в вопросе, потому что сейчас у вас там та ошибка, к чему относится мой первый комментарий.

Comment: Я вам уже говорил в чем проблема - у вас база (EF), это Model слой, который не имеет INPC. Сделайте классы, которые будут предназначены для привязки и пусть они получают данные из базы, не используйте напрямую Model. В этих классах вызывайте INPC, который и обновит интерфейс. Сейчас же у вас данные в свойство приходят, да, только интерфейс не знает про то, что свойство изменилось.